# How to display the top 3 biggest values of an array in a textbox?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, max, textfield

So I'm creating a Flash game and I save the scores in sharedObject. I have successfully saved the scores to an Array. Here is the code:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var shared:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("sharedmean");
var tempArray:Array = new Array();

if (shared.data.score) {
 tempArray = shared.data.score;
}

tempArray.push(scoreTotal);
shared.data.score = tempArray;

trace(tempArray);
shared.flush();
shared.close();
```

and the trace result is:

```
500,100,0,100,100,0,300
```

I've created the highscore textbox and want to display the 3 biggest values from that array.
I want the textbox to display this:

```
Highscore 1: 500
Highscore 2: 300
Highscore 3: 100
```

How do I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` method, sorts values in an array according to its parameters.
Here we use `Array.NUMERIC` parameter to sort by numeric values.also we push `Array.DESCENDING` parameter to sort value from biggest to smallest.That makes an easier access to the three first values:

```
tempArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
//don't forget to push " | " between parameters
```

now

```
textField.text= "Highscore 1:"+tempArray[0]+"\n Highscore 2:"+tempArray[1]+"\n Highscore 3:"+tempArray[2];
```

I H☺P E this helps !

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search would have gotten you the following

```
tempArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
```